# Rewiring a sewing machine

Tags: appliances

I have an old sewing machine with a non-polarized plug.  I would like to replace the cord and plug with a grounded, polarized cord and plug.  Can I simply connect the new cord's hot wire to the controller cable and motor and the neutral to the uncontrolled side of the motor and screw the ground wire into the metal case?

Comment: Can you include a picture of what you want to connect to??

Comment: Small appliance repair is [specifically off-topic](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for this site.

Answer (score 5):

Yes your method would be sound. Controlling the hot is normal.